# FTP not happening on RHEL 6 Server

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, ftp

I am not able to ftp to the server from a client. 
I can ping the server from VM, can ssh as well, but cannot ftp. 
I am using my base machine as Ubuntu 14.04. Below is the `ifconfig` output:

```
raghav@raghav-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:63:bb:e5:ee:29  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6302 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6302 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:603664 (603.6 KB)  TX bytes:603664 (603.6 KB)

ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:38:96:7f:5c:97  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c238:96ff:fe7f:5c97/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:354373 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69134 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:121914289 (121.9 MB)  TX bytes:12476694 (12.4 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01  
          inet addr:192.168.5.1  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08  
          inet addr:172.16.172.1  Bcast:172.16.172.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:85 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Now I have installed VM player on the machine and configured RHEL 6 Server with the below configuration:

```
raghav@raghav-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:63:bb:e5:ee:29  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6302 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6302 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:603664 (603.6 KB)  TX bytes:603664 (603.6 KB)

ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:38:96:7f:5c:97  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c238:96ff:fe7f:5c97/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:354373 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69134 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:121914289 (121.9 MB)  TX bytes:12476694 (12.4 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01  
          inet addr:192.168.5.1  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08  
          inet addr:172.16.172.1  Bcast:172.16.172.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:85 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

On the server I have deployed a VM RHEL 6 with following configuration:

```
Ipaddr: 192.168.122.217
```

While configuring the network NAT protocol was used. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please let me know if any further info is required from my side. I can ping the server from VM , can ssh as well. but cannot ftp

Answer (score 1):

Appears you need to install `ftp`.  Such an insecure protocol isn't installed/enabled by default on RHEL 6.

`yum install proftpd` will install ftp.

Comment: Hey steve thanksfor thr ans. Indeed i requireD the install the ftp service. For that i installed vsftpd. Also had to work with SElinux to be disaed for aome ftp directories. And it started working.